# How to get next autoincrement integer?

Tags: c#, sqlite

So I have an SQLite database with a table that has a column named `id` set up to auto increment.

Is there a way to retrieve what it will next increment to?

Comment: Does it increment by `n`? If so, you can do max + `n`. I would assume it'd be as reliable as getting the next one (if you're afraid of it being async and a new one being inserted before that)

Comment: That might give some troubles when some elements are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a standard (incremeented by 1) auto increment you can use the

```
select last_insert_rowid();
```

command, and then increment it by one.

You can find out more informations about it here:

http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-autoincrement-insert-value-primary-key

Comment: Sometimes the user may choose to enter their own ID. Please do not ask me why.

Comment: While I am not exactly sure of how the autoincrement feature would work under those conditions, the first thing that comes to my mind to work around it is to create an AFTER INSERT Trigger that stores in a specific tablet the value of the last inserted ID so that you can access it reliably at any time.

Comment: as long as this is single user, single thread , non productive use. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx  You cant get a guaranteed number you will be issued in a multi thread or multi access scenario. You can find out what number would will likely be issued.

Comment: This does not work if the current connection has not inserted anything, and will be wrong if some other connection has inserted a row after that.